# Updating facebook like button with Ajax

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I just finished a small website 100% based on ajax.But i have a problem in updating the links of the facebook Like buttons.

I used simply the facebook generated [code](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and i included the graph meta tags. when the users presses a button it loads a new youtube video, i update the meta tag

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mySite.com/"/>
```

using jQuery this way :

```
$("meta[property=og:url]").attr("content", nUrl);
```

nUrl is the new page url that contains the new randomly selected video.

When i hit "Like" it simply grab hit "Like" it simply grab the original og:url meta tag content and now the new on set by ajax.
 How to update with javascript the like button url ? What is wrong in what i did ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's what i did to solve my problem for other people who have the same:
 Add this to your site :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" >
```

This will add the fbml to your site. Then use the FBML version of the like button (or comment system, or whatever), for like i used this :

```
<span id="fbLike"><fb:like href="http://www.your-site.com?v=1" send="false" layout="button_count" width="80" show_faces="true"></fb:like></span>
```

Now to have a new facebook like button each time the user make an Ajax action, just add this jquery code to where ever you handle this action in your client-side code:

```
var nUrl = "http://www.your-site.com?v="+toPlayId.substring(1);
$( '#fbLike' ).html('<fb:like href="'+nUrl+'" send="false" layout="button_count" width="80" show_faces="true" />');
        if (typeof FB  != "undefined"){
        FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fbLike'));}
```

You basically just replace the  where your button is with a new one.
nUrl is the new link you want your new button to point to.
You don't need a real new URL just add a parameter to the url so that your ajax knows what to display when he finds the parameter.
That's all.

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but the part about using the `FB.XFBML.parse` finally clicked.  Rewriting the html inside of the span is ingenious to get the new like button.

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify meta tags with AJAX or javascript.  Setup server-side scripting to correctly set them the first time.

When you Like/share a URL on Facebook, Facebook will make an HTTP request to the URL and parse the meta tags that it sees.

Comment: yes but the like button should point the good page url, if it just point you-fake.com i can't know what video the user liked to set the correct meta tag

Comment: Yeah, that is why I said server-side scripting.  I use GET variables to determine the server-side logic for meta tag settings.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update the OG tag with Javascript. Facebook will make a serverside request to your server and this must return OG tags which represent that object.

You'll need to create a URL for every object on your site - something like:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/video/VIDEO_ID
```

As your video in-page changes with Ajax, you render a new like button which points at a URL like this. Hitting this URL without JS should render the correct OG tags - this is how Facebook will see your page. You can then add a javascript redirect (window.top.location = NEW URL) to redirect the user into ajax-based video player.